# Installing phonegap app on device

Tags: cordova, installation, device

I have created a little app using "phonegap" (which means that  i have installed "phonegap", created a "my-app" directory and edited the HTML/CSS files.
No i have the app lying there (at the local drive of my PC) and wonder how i can get it working on my handy (samsung galaxy s4 mini).
So how do i get the files onto my device so that i can run the app as any other app i have downloaded at the playstore?

I tried connecting the device via usb, activated the USB debugging mode.
Then via command line i opened the my-app directory and executed "phonegap run android" ... but i can't find the app on my device.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to create an APK of your application and then, store it on your device and run it from your file browser.

Otherwise, you can use IDE like [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/) or [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) to compile and run your app directly on your device and get the ADB debug tool.